# What are the ways to avoid object mutation in Dart-lang?

Tags: object, dart, immutability, mutation

If we take the following snippet as an example:

```
main() {
    List<int> array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    List<int> newArray = change(array);

    print(array); // [99, 2, 3, 4]
    print(newArray); // [99, 2, 3, 4]
    print(newArray == array); // true
}

change(List<int> array) {
    var newArray = array;
    newArray[0] = 99;
    return newArray;
}
```

The original array gets mutated. I was expecting that by passing the array (object) to the change function and assigning a new variable to it that I could avoid mutation. I am aware that the [built_collection library](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/built_collection) seems like the main go-to for immutable collections. Is there any native way the core library that would allow for a deep freeze or prevent side effects (operations inside another function)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects are passed by reference. This is by design: objects are often large data structures and internally making a copy every time an object is passed to a function can be very inefficient. (This is the same approach as that used by other major object oriented languages.)

As a result, `array` and `newArray` are two names for the *same* underlying `List` in your code.

If you want to explicitly create a new list, just change

```
var newArray = array;
```

to:

```
var newArray = new List.from(array);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap an array in an `UnmodifiableListView` from `dart:collection` and pass this around instead of the array itself. I think this is the most basic buit-in way.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Though this approach would raise an exception when the `UnmodifiableListView` is passed (and tried to get changed) in another function.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you modify an unmodifyable array?